# Footer - Different Odd and Even pages in Word 2007

Tags: microsoft-word-2007

I've tick the 'Different odd & even pages', clicked 'Next section' and typed 2. All my even pages changed to "2". If I retyped page 4, every even pages changes to "4". I want to keep my odd pages' footer right and even pages' footer left, with continuing page number. How??? Thanks~

Answer (score 0):

Do not manually type the number you want.

When in footer-edit-mode, go to the design tab, and select Page Number on the left.